# Why align-self do not work as text-align in CSS?

Tags: html, css, text-align

I will use extracts and simplify for explanation purposes.

I was looking for errors in a webpage I designed some months ago and I found the following problem in the logo section:

```
<div>
 <a id="logo" href="index.html" title="Página Principal" class="logo center">
   <img src="img/mainlogo.png" alt="Corporate-logo" title="Página Principal">
 </a>
</div>
```

Consider that the parent container has: display: flex; and there are another elements (child) inside.

In the stylesheet CSS

```
.logo {
  flex:1;
  align-self: center;
}

.center {
text-align: center;
}
```

As soon as I remove the center class the logo goes to left (default value I suppose). I do not understand with alig-self do not place the logo in the center.

What am I missing or not understanding?, I do not want to use the center class to center the logo.

Comment: Unless the div in your sample markup has `display: flex` (or grid), align-self will have no effect. When you say "the parent container" do you mean something above the div in your sample?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to set is the `display` property.

`display: flex;` instead of `flex: 1;`

(`flex: 1` is shorthand for setting `flex-grow` to 1)

Your alignment can then be defined using the `justify-content` and `align-items` properties.

Answer (score 0):

`align-self` will work as you have it if you add `display: flex` to the parent. The snippet shows a more common method.

> align-self allows the default alignment (or the one specified by align-items) to be overridden for individual flex items.

[SOURCE](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#examples)

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <a id="logo" href="index.html" title="Página Principal" class="logo center">
    <img src="img/mainlogo.png" alt="Corporate-logo" title="Página Principal">
  </a>
</div>
```